# Is there away to have 2 buttons and 2 diff href?

Tags: html

I have 2 buttons but I want 2 different links when clicked.

This is what I tried

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="add.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="ADD" class="add">
    </form>
    <form action="view.php">
        <input type="submit" value="VIEW" class="view">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Absolutely; did you try it? Note that you've set up two different forms to post data though -- if you want a simple navigation, you're looking for `<a href="location">Link</a>`.

Comment: are the links more correct?

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to do. If you want to merely *navigate*, you definitely want `<a href="location">Link</a>`. If you want to send data somewhere, you'll want to do it the way you have done it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms are intended to be used when you want to take some user input and process it / send it to a server.

For just navigation (links), it is much simpler to use **anchor tags (`<a>`)**, with its `href` attribute containing the link's URL, and the text of the link specified inside the `<a>` tag.

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link to Stack Overflow</a>
```